# Existence of the laplace transform $sin(8t^{3})$

Tags: laplace-transform

Apparently the laplace transform of $sin(8t^3)$ doesn't exist. No program lets me calculate it. I was asked if it existed in an exam and I said yes because it happens to meet all the criteria. Can anyone tell me if it exists or not?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\displaystyle\int_0^\infty e^{-st}\sin(8t^3)\;dt$ isn't an elementary function.

Comment: Hmm. To be honest I don't know what an elementary function is (I'm looking it up), but why can't you say it exists if all criteria are met? The function is continuous, its of exponential order etc.

Comment: Read through [Liouville's Theorem](http://www.sci.ccny.cuny.edu/~ksda/PostedPapers/liouv06.pdf)

Comment: Basically there are functions that aren't elementary functions such as $\displaystyle \int e^{-x^2} \;dx$

Comment: Crap :(. I hope my teacher didn't expect me to know this. Thanks though.

Comment: So the typical conditions for the existence of the laplace transform should also refer to the integral existence?

Comment: Laplace transform may exist but you there isn't an elementary function for that transform. If the integral converges, the function is of exponential order, piecewise continuous, etc.. then Laplace transform exist. However the integral may be an ugly one. Just like this one.

Comment: In fact there is a theorem that states that if the function is of exponential order and piecewise continuous on $[0,\infty)$ then the Laplace transform of the function exists. Again, let me stress that this doesn't imply the existence of a elementary function to express the antiderivative.

Comment: Ok, so so would you say it exists then? It does meet the criteria, doesn't it?

Comment: It does, indeed.

Comment: Not sure it is better looking than the Laplace transform definition itself, but according to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4809715/laplace-transform-of-ftn-for-n3), this specific transform should be equal to $\frac{8\sqrt{s}}{3\pi} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(t^2+64).\sqrt{t}} . K_{\frac{1}{3}} 
\Big( \frac{2}{3} \frac{s^{\frac{3}{2}}} {\sqrt{3t}} \Big) dt$